# Avoid repetition of array push

Tags: arrays, angularjs, json

I have created an object and inside the object I had created an array where I am pushing an object which is coming from a json data.

```
$scope.pagenumArr = {"attribute":[],"_name":"pagenum","__prefix":"xsl"};
            if ($scope.pagenumArr.attribute.indexOf($scope.contentObj.stylesheet["attribute-set"][4].attribute) == -1) {
                $scope.pagenumArr.attribute.push($scope.contentObj.stylesheet["attribute-set"][4].attribute);
            }
            console.log($scope.pagenumArr);
```

`scope.contentObj.stylesheet["attribute-set"][4].attribute` is the data which I am trying to push which is

```
{
  "_name": "font-weight",
  "__prefix": "xsl",
  "__text": "bold"
}
```

I am replacing the old object with new object

```
//replace old pagenum object with new array
            $scope.contentObj.stylesheet["attribute-set"][4] = $scope.pagenumArr;
            console.log($scope.contentObj);
```

So when I reload my app , another array is been created inside the array `"attribute":[]`. I just need previous push object inside the array. How can I prevent repeatation of push  in my code ? where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You could try using

```
if(angular.isUndefined(nameofobject.dataPath[KeyOfData])){
   nameofobject.dataPath = KeyOfData;
}
```

Comment: I didn't get this `nameofobject` . Can you please suggest according to my data ?

Comment: 'pagenumArr', which is an object you have given an annoying called with an array name convension

Comment: How can I mention `KeyOfData` ?  What if I need to search by values ?

Comment: key of data is the data that your going to store inside this object, it would look alike {Key:info} where key is the same as dataPath and Info is keyOfData

Comment: I think you didn't get what I am trying to do. I am having an object like `{attr:{Key:info}}`. Now I want `attr` object to be an array. like `{attr:[{Key:info}]}`. And after this im checking if object is there in array. I want to get replace this `{attr:{Key:info}}` --> to  this  `{attr:[{Key:info}]}`. once if `attr` is an  object. And if  array `{attr:[{Key:info}]}` is found then skip.

Comment: JavaScript doesn't allow you to make objects where the value is an array inside of an object.

Comment: After this i have more objects like `{Key:info}` which I am successfully pushing into array ex:- `{attr:[ {Key:info},{Key:info},{Key:info} ] }` but I think somewhere I am logically doing mistake. When I am loading the page again now this array becomes like this  :- `{attr:[ [ {Key:info},{Key:info},{Key:info} ] ,{Key:info},{Key:info} ] }` . Means another array is being created inside. I want to avoid this.

Comment: use `if(angular.isdefined(attr[Counter][key])` to check if the item already exists, put this in a` forEach` loop